# What does Include() do in LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

I tried to do a lot of research but I'm more of a db guy - so even the explanation in the MSDN doesn't make any sense to me. Can anyone please explain, and provide some examples on what `Include()` statement does in the term of `SQL` query?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Let's say for instance you want to get a list of all your customers:

```
var customers = context.Customers.ToList();
```

And let's assume that each `Customer` object has a reference to its set of `Orders`, and that each `Order` has references to `LineItems` which may also reference a `Product`.

As you can see, selecting a top-level object with many related entities could result in a query that needs to pull in data from many sources.  As a performance measure, `Include()` allows you to indicate which related entities should be read from the database as part of the same query.

Using the same example, this might bring in all of the related order headers, but none of the other records:

```
var customersWithOrderDetail = context.Customers.Include("Orders").ToList();
```

As a final point since you asked for SQL, the first statement without `Include()` could generate a simple statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers;
```

The final statement which calls `Include("Orders")` may look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers JOIN Orders ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId;
```

Comment: Thank you. Using your example, can I say if I want to also include the `LineItems` and `Products`, the LINQ query should look like this: `var customersWithOrderDetail = context.Customers.Include("Orders").Include("LineItems").Include("Products").ToList();` ?

Comment: Yes, you can chain multiple calls to `Include()` to capture objects along difference "paths". If you want objects in the same path you only have to make one call that specifies the entire path. Since `LineItems` and `Products` don't share any path components you do need separate calls.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Include? I am pretty sure i worked on solutions where I could get related objects without using it.

Comment: @Jepzen It depends on whether you're using lazy-loaded entities or not.

Comment: @Yuck, I believe this works when you are using lazy-loading, in case of eager loading, you don't need to use "include" statement, but this definitely will result in performance issues.
Please correct me on this.

Comment: @Yuck which type of join it is?

Comment: @Tk1993 it is `Left Join` when the foreignkey is nullable and `Inner Join` when it is not.

Comment: whats the difference of this from 'join'

Comment: `Join(...)` syntax allows you to specify the logic used for the `join`.  `Include(...)` does not, and will build the `join` statement based on the configured relationship between entities.

Comment: To complement the answer and understand how does `Include()` know what keys to use, see the [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) documentation article, which specify two ways (conventions and FluentApi), and the [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#relationship-attributes-inverseproperty-and-foreignkey) article which specify a third way (using attributes).

Answer (score 34):

I just wanted to add that "Include" is part of eager loading. It is described in Entity Framework 6 tutorial by Microsoft. Here is the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

---

Excerpt from the linked page:

> Here are several ways that the Entity Framework can load related data into the navigation properties of an entity:
>
> **Lazy loading.** When the entity is first read, related data isn't retrieved. However, the first time you attempt to access a navigation property, the data required for that navigation property is automatically retrieved. This results in multiple queries sent to the database — one for the entity itself and one each time that related data for the entity must be retrieved. The DbContext class enables lazy loading by default.
>
> **Eager loading.** When the entity is read, related data is retrieved along with it. This typically results in a single join query that retrieves all of the data that's needed. You specify eager loading by using the **`Include`** method.
>
> **Explicit loading.** This is similar to lazy loading, except that you explicitly retrieve the related data in code; it doesn't happen automatically when you access a navigation property. You load related data manually by getting the object state manager entry for an entity and calling the Collection.Load method for collections or the Reference.Load method for properties that hold a single entity. (In the following example, if you wanted to load the Administrator navigation property, you'd replace `Collection(x => x.Courses)` with `Reference(x => x.Administrator)`.) Typically you'd use explicit loading only when you've turned lazy loading off.
>
> Because they don't immediately retrieve the property values, lazy loading and explicit loading are also both known as deferred loading.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as enforcing Eager-Loading in a scenario where your sub-items would otherwise be lazy-loading.

The Query EF is sending to the database will yield a larger result at first, but on access no follow-up queries will be made when accessing the included items.

On the other hand, without it, EF would execute separte queries later, when you first access the sub-items.

Answer (score 0):

include() method just to include the related entities.
but what happened on sql is based on the relationship between those entities which you are going to include what the data you going to fetch.

your LINQ query decides what type of joins have to use, there could be left outer joins there could be inner join there could be right joins etc...
@Corey Adler

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you should use `.Include()` and `.ThenInclude()` **only when returning the object (NOT THE QUERYABLE) with the "other table property"**.

As a result, it should only be used when returning APIs' objects, not in your intra-application.