# How can I filter a DataTable without brute-forcing it?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I populate a DataTable with a Stored Procedure. In one particular instance, though, I need to filter those results down to a subset of what they normally are, based on the vaue of a member value in the result set that is not one of the parameters provided the Stored Procedure.

ISTM that it should be doable to filter the DataTable, assigning a subset of itself to itself for this singular scenrio.

I don't know what exact code I need for this, but the pseudocode would, I think, be something like this ("dtUsage" is a DataTable):

```
dtUsage = dtUsage.Rows Where MemberNo in ["0451", "050", "067"];
```

I could use another DataTable temporarily, and loop through the first one, conditionally adding rows to the second one, but I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this with LINQ or so.

### UPDATE

Based on what I see [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select), something like this might work:

```
DataRow[] result = dtUsage.Select("MemberNo IN [\"103\",\"016\",\"04501\"]");
```

...but how to then assign result to the data table?

Neither this:

```
dtUsage = result;
```

...nor this:

```
dtUsage.Rows = result;
```

...compiles. Nor does this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow drp in result)
{
    dt.Add(drp);
}
```

Comment: [Datatable.Select](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select)

Comment: datatable.defaultview.rowfilter

Comment: look up "includes"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq

Comment: Re: update: Every datatable comes with a free built in DataView hidden in the defaultview property which allows actual filtering without building new queries or tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this I guess.

```
dtUsage = dtUsage.Where(data => data.MemberNo  == '0451' || data.MemberNo   == '050' || data.MemberNo   == '067')
```

Edit: Or maybe this?

```
var results = from row in dtUsage.AsEnumerable()
where (row.Field<string>("MemberNo") == "0451" ||
row.Field<string>("MemberNo") == "050" ||
row.Field<string>("MemberNo") == "067")
select row;
```

Comment: dtUsage does not have a "Where" available to use.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want something like:

```
var result = from x in dtUsage.AsEnumerable()
where new string[]{"0451", "050", "067"}.Contains(x.Field<string>("MemberNo"))
select x;
```

Comment: Isn't this logic backwards? I am looking for MemberNos that contain one of those values, and this logic seems to me to do the opposite.

Comment: I usually use this format : List<DataRow> results = dtUsage.AsEnumerable().Where(x => new string[]{"0451", "050", "067"}.Contains(x.Field<string>("MemberNo")).ToList();