# Oracle Entity Framework name is already used by an existing object

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I am trying to make the change from leveraging entity framework on my Local SQL DB to my production oracle database. I have gone as installing oracle.entityframework via nuget and making the required changes to my web.config file.

```
  <dataSources>
    <dataSource alias="<DatasourceName>" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xxx.xx.xx.xxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<serverName>))) " />
  </dataSources>

<add name="TestDBContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=UName;Password=PW;Data Source=<DatasourceName>" />

  <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

With some changes to the default schema settings I got the update-database command executing successfully and can see the corresponding db tables are created in my oracle instance, however when I hit run on my app I receive a **name is already used by an existing object** error when my code attempts to make its first db call as seen in the attached screenshot.

[Already Exists Error ScreenCap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYjgc.png)

I suspect that I have missed something regarding the creation and deletion of the table at run time but am at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also regarding versioning. I using MVC 5.2.3 with EF 6

Thanks

Comment: What if instead .Include you use a Join in your Linq query or just try a simpler query first https://stackoverflow.com/a/26661930

Comment: I tried a simpler query with the same result

Comment: For your second error returned by Oracle could you try running Oracle SQL Profiler to see the query causing it..