# Object is null when configuring one to one relationship with fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have three classes: `Role`, `Permission` and `RolePermission`(role permission is the third table in a many to many *relationship*)

```
public class Role : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
}

public class RolePermission : Entity
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then I used `fluentAPI` in order to configure *relationship*:

For `Role`:

```
HasMany(role => role.RolePermissions)
            .WithRequired(rolePermission => rolePermission.Role)
            .HasForeignKey(rolePermission => rolePermission.RoleId);
```

For `Permission`:

```
HasMany(permission => permission.RolePermissions)
            .WithRequired(rolePermission => rolePermission.Permission)
            .HasForeignKey(rolePermission => rolePermission.PermissionId);
```

For `RolePermission`:

```
HasRequired(rolePermission => rolePermission.Permission)
            .WithMany(permission => permission.RolePermissions)
            .HasForeignKey(rolePermission => rolePermission.PermissionId);

HasRequired(rolePermission => rolePermission.Role)
            .WithMany(role => role.RolePermissions)
            .HasForeignKey(rolePermission => rolePermission.RoleId);
```

The problem is that only `Role` object is populated.

[image]

Comment: The code in this question pertains to setting up a relationship. The reported issue in this question pertains to related data not being loaded automatically. These are two different things that have little to do with one another. Show us the code of where you launch your query from. Did you miss an Include somewhere? Have you accessed (and therefore lazily loaded) the Role nav prop, but not the Permission nav prop? I would like to see the code starting from where you launch the query up to where you inspect this object (as per your screenshot)

Comment: @Flater, this is the query : `var user = _userRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(us => us.Email == email); var userPermissions = user.UserRoles.First().Role.RolePermissions.Select(rp => rp.Permission).ToList();`

Comment: @Flater, yes, I have to use include and the problem is solved. This is the solution, so please post it as an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in this question pertains to setting up a relationship. The reported issue in this question pertains to related data not being loaded automatically. These are two different things that have little to do with one another.
Did you miss an Include somewhere? Have you accessed (and therefore lazily loaded) the Role nav prop, but not the Permission nav prop? I would like to see the code starting from where you launch the query up to where you inspect this object (as per your screenshot)

You responded with the requested code:

```
var user = _userRepository
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(us => us.Email == email); 

var userPermissions = 
           user.UserRoles
               .First()
               .Role
               .RolePermissions
               .Select(rp => rp.Permission)
               .ToList();
```

If you insert an [`Include()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq) statement in your query, you will see that the `Permission` will actually be fetched correctly.

I am not quite sure which object you're inspecting. The screenshot tells me you're looking at a `RolePermission`, but the posted code suggests that you fetch a list of `Permission` objects.

Regardless, you seem to already have fixed it using an `Include`:

> **Mihai Alexandru-Ionut** @Flater, yes, I have to use include and the problem is solved. This is the solution, so please post it as an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`Id` Property is missing for both `Role` and `Permission` tables. When you say `RoleId` property in `RolePermission` table, EF looks for Id Property in `Role` table.

Update your Role and Permission tables like this and give a try:

```
public class Role : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Role` inherits `Entity` class which has a virtual memeber called `Id`. I forgot to mention that.