# why does "Unexpected token )" get thrown to me when using the for command?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am using the for command and when I do `for(i < 4) { i++ }` it pops out: `Unexpected token ) at line *line of the command*`

I have tried moving some variables and moving where the for command is, even checking StackOverflow, but I can not find an answer. This is strange since it has not happened in the past.

```js
function learnEng() {
    while(generationNum <= generations) {
        for(i <= 4) {
            i++;
        }
    document.write("<h2>sentence "+generationNum+": "+output+"</h2>");
        generationNum++;
        }
}
learnEng();
```

I didn't expect to get the error because this is the first time I have gotten it, and it spat out an error, and Its sometimes on the line that the `for(){}` command is on and sometimes it is not, but I know the `for(){}` command is causing it because it doesn't happen when its not there.

Comment: Well, this is just not an accepted syntax. Did you glance at the documentation ?

Comment: Look at [Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq) (i.e. you are doing it wrong)

Comment: What is `generationNum`, `output` and `generations`?

Comment: Also **do** declare your variables. A free i like this is a ton of bugs

Comment: I do declare my variables, also I am making an AI to learn English.

Comment: Of course it points to your "for(i <= 4) {", where do you have that syntax from? Can you please point to a documentation? Where is your variable initializer, where the increment? A normal for loop expects 3 (three) expressions. Why do you think something like that could work, if you don't stick to the syntax your language expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) requires three (optional) expressions, separated by semicolons:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

If you want to leave out any of the optional expressions, you still need the semi-colons.

For example, here is a for statement with none of the optional expressions:

```
var i = 0;

for (;;) {
  if (i > 3) break;
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot since I haven't used the ```for``` command in a while

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to invalid `for` syntax. You need to insert 2 `;`.

```
function learnEng() {
    while(generationNum <= generations) {
        for(;i <= 4;) {
            i++;
        }
     document.write("<h2>sentence "+generationNum+": "+output+"</h2>");
        generationNum++;
        }
}
learnEng();
```