# Entity Framework Core code-first approach one to many relationship returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework Core, in my code I have a number of `Questions` class objects, and a list of choices to those questions. My query list of `Choices` always returns Null.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Questions
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string  Question { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Choices> choices { get; set; }
}

public class Choices
{
    [Key]
    public int ChoicesId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public Questions questions  { get; set; }
    public string Choice { get; set; }
}

public class SqlUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext context;

    public SqlUserRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<Questions> getAllQuestions()
    {
        return context.questions.ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this O/p. choices always returns null

```
[
    { "questionID":1, "question":"which is your fav.heroien", "choices":null },
    { "questionID":2, "question":"which is your fav.hero", "choices":null  } 
]
```

I expect this output

```
[{"questionID":1,"question":"which is your fav.heroien","choices":[{"choicesId":5,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"kajol Agarwal"},{"choicesId":6,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"Thammanna Bhatia"},{"choicesId":7,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"Anushka Shetty"},{"choicesId":8,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"Keerthi Suresh"}]},{"questionID":2,"question":"which is your fav.hero","choices":[{"choicesId":1,"questionId":2,"questions":null,"choice":"upendera"},{"choicesId":2,"questionId":2,"questions":null,"choice":"real star"},{"choicesId":3,"questionId":2,"questions":null,"choice":"Super star"},{"choicesId":4,"questionId":2,"questions":null,"choice":"Only star"}]}]
```

Comment: Tried using `Include()` to also load the choices directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Questions> getAllQuestions()
  {
    return context.questions.Include(q => q.choices).ToList();
  }
```

Include() allows you to indicate which related entities should be read from the database as part of the same query.

The final statement which calls Include("Choices") may look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM questions JOIN Choices ON questions.Id = Choices.questionsId;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26661930/8006943

Comment: it retuns invalid json format `[{"questionID":1,"question":"which is your fav.heroien","choices":[{"choicesId":5,"questionId":1`

Comment: I expect this output `[{"questionID":1,"question":"which is your fav.heroien","choices":[{"choicesId":5,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"kajol Agarwal"},{"choicesId":6,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"Thammanna Bhatia"},{"choicesId":7,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"Anushka Shetty"},{"choicesId":8,"questionId":1,"questions":null,"choice":"Keerthi Suresh"}]},{"questionID":2,"question":"which is your fav.hero","choices":[{"choicesId":1,"questionId":2,"questions":null,"choice":"upendera"},{"choicesId":4,"questionId":2,"questions":null,"choice":"Only star"}]}]`

Comment: you need return a few choice? if yes read this https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration

Answer (score 1):

According to [EF Core-Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) documentaiton you have to use `.Include` to load your related data as follows:

```
public List<Questions> getAllQuestions()
{
    return context.questions.Include(q => q.choices).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to build your app with code first approach and with relational data the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) will guide step by step do the things apply the code first approach.