# ASP.NET Core 2.2 IdentityUser not retrieved with model

Tags: c#, linq, razor, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I have a Model, it has a property of the Type IdentityUser, like so:

```
public class Foo {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // working properties omitted

    public IdentityUser LastChangeBy { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to retrieve the Model from the DB with efcore I get no errors, but the `LastChangeBy` property is `null`, even though it was created with a (valid) User. I even double checked the Ids in the user's table against the one in the model's table.

My (admittedly naive) LINQ in the model looks like this:

```
Foos = from foo in db.Foos
       select foo;
```

There are no errors printed to the console, the Site loads as normal, breakpoints reveal, that directly coming from the DB the user is `null` already. I did not modify any settings from the default settings in my DbContext (which is derived from `IdentityDbContext`) and the current migrations are applied.

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: @GertArnold shouldn't it load the missing stuff anyway, but slower then? I also dont have the ``LastChangeBy`` property declared as virtual.

Comment: No, EF-core doesn't have lazy loading as default.

Comment: @GertArnold oh, i was used to ef 6... could you post a full answer, so i can accept it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq