# MVVM + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-core

i have model "Appointments"

```
public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Checkout { get; set; }


        public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Staff { get; set; }
        
    }
```

and this is DataGrid in View(WPF)

```
<DataGrid
            x:Name="DataGridCalendar"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3FCB23 " />
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F35656 " />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=StartTime}"
                    Header="StartTime"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />

                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=EndTime}"
                    Header="EndTime"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=StaffId}"
                    Header="Employee"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Client.Fullname}"
                    Header="Client"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=ServiceId}"
                    Header="Service"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"
                    Header="Price"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Notes}"
                    Header="Note"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    x:Name="Status"
                    Width="*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                    Header="Status"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"
                    IsReadOnly="False" />


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

in the database, the client, employee, etc. are bound by a foreign key with the Appointments table

the datagrid displays the id of the client, employee, etc., how can I display the name and surname?

and this is a piece of ViewModel

```
class CalendarViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private List<Appointment> appointment;
        public List<Appointment> Appointments { get => appointment; set => OnChanged(out appointment, value); }

        private async void UpdateTable()
        {
            using BeautySalonDBContext db = new BeautySalonDBContext();
            await db.Appointments.LoadAsync();
            Appointments = db.Appointments.Local.ToList();
        }
```

How can I join these tables by ID and display the first and last name in the window?

Comment: Using linq, what you want is include. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq  That will eager read whichever related data into the appropriate collection. You should translate your model data into a similar structure of viewmodels and bind that. And you should always filter your data. Never just load an entire table into memory. That's ok with 10 test records. When you go live there will probably be many records and dragging 10 million records off the server onto each client won't work so well.

Comment: oh no no no! you're doing MVVM wrong. model is not VM and the bindable properties of the VM cannot be models. you need to have AppointmentVM and a pattern of your choice to convert model into VM. If you're using EF, then you don't implement a model, let it auto-generate. just implement the VM.