# How to use linq include function in generic type

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, include

I want to get single employee  and get many projects againt to this user.How to use include function in my query
_dbContext.Set     <T>().FindAsync(id)

Comment: Your question should contain [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Include() do in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq)

Comment: You do something like `context.Employees.Find(id).Include(e => e.Projects)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be what you are looking for. I tried fairly exhaustively to try to use the Generic notation with a reflective Include, and found it difficult.
So instead the `FullFindAsync` method will take in a `Type` object which you could use in place of the `T`. is then has `param objects[]` to use as the key for searching

```
public static async Task<object> FullFindAsync(this DbContext context, Type entityType, params object[] keyValues)
{
    object entity = null;

    //handle an Interface as a passed in type
    if (entityType.IsInterface)
    {
        //get all Types of Models in the DbContext that implement the Interface
        var implementedModels = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                                    .Select(et => et.ClrType)
                                        .Where(t => entityType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
                                            .ToList();

        //loop through all Models and try to find the object via the parameters
        foreach (var modelType in implementedModels)
        { //TODO: it would be nice to not have to do a find on every Model, but only optimize if this has performance hits
            entity = await context.FindAsync(modelType, keyValues);
            if (entity != null) break;
        }
    }
    else
        //find the object, via regular Find
        entity = await context.FindAsync(entityType, keyValues);

    //didnt find the object
    if (entity == null) return null;

    //loop through all navigation properties
    foreach (var navigation in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //skip NotMapped properties (to avoid context collection error)
        if (context.Entry(entity).Metadata.FindNavigation(navigation.Name) == null)
            continue;

        //check and load reference and collection properties
        if (typeof(IMyRootType).IsAssignableFrom(navigation.PropertyType))
            context.Entry(entity).Reference(navigation.Name).Load();
        if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(navigation.PropertyType))
            context.Entry(entity).Collection(navigation.Name).Load();
    }

    return entity;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:
`var myItem = await dbContext.FullFindAsync(typeof(T), someId);`

What I did is have every class within the context implement a simple Interface that contains the unique key. So you may need to modify the method to suit your needs, but hopefully it can help.
Do note that is can be pretty inefficient on large datasets, so use with caution.