# LINQ with joins and group generates enormous query and is slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

My Entity structure is as follows:

```cs
public class DisbursementItem
{
    public int DisbursementNumber;
    public int IDDisbursementItem;
    public int IDReceiptItem;
    public decimal Amount;
    public decimal MeasureUnit;
    public decimal PricePerMU;
    public decimal PriceTotal;
    public Disbursement Disbursement_IDDisbursement;
    public int IDDisbursementNumber;
}

public class Disbursement
{
    public int DisbursementNumber;
    DateTime date;
    DisbursementType DType;
    string Note;
    string Subscriber;
    Subscriber SubscriberModel;
    string ItemType;
    int ProcessNumber;
}

public class Subscriber 
{
    public string Name
    public string Address;
    public string City;
}

public class DisbursementDescription
{
    public int IDDisbursementItem;
    public string Description;
}

public class Receipt
{
    public int IDReceiptItem;
    public int ItemNumber;
}

public class StorageCard 
{
    public int ItemNumber;
    public string StorageCardGroup;
    public string StorageCardName;
}
```

And my EF6 LINQ query is:

```cs
DateTime from;
DateTime to;
var result = context.DisbursementItem
    .Where(x => x.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Date <= to && x.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Date >= from)
    .Join(context.DisbursementDescription, di => di.IDDisbursementItem, dd => dd.IDDisbursementItem, (di, dd) => new {di = di, desc = dd.Description})
    .Join(context.Receipt, x => x.di.IDReceiptItem, r => r.IDReceiptItem, (x, r) => new { di = x.di, desc = x.desc, r = r })
    .Join(context.StorageCard, x => x.r.ItemNumber, sc => sc.ItemNumber, (x, sc) => new { di = x.di, desc = x.desc, r = x.r, sc = sc})
    .GroupBy(g => new {g.di.DisbursementNumber, g.sc.ItemNumber, g.di.MeasureUnit})
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Date = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Date,
        DisbursementNumber = x.Key.DisbursementNumber,
        DType = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.DType,
        Note = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Note,
        Subscriber = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Subscriber,
        SubscriberName = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.SubscriberModel.Name,
        SubscriberAddress = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.SubscriberModel.Address,
        SubscriberCity = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.SubscriberModel.City,
        ItemNumber = x.FirstOrDefault().sc.ItemNumber,
        StorageCardGroup = x.FirstOrDefault().sc.StorageCardGroup,
        StorageCardName = x.FirstOrDefault().sc.StorageCardName,
        Amount = x.Sum(y => y.di.Amount),
        PricePerMU = x.FirstOrDefault().di.PricePerMU,
        PriceTotal = x.Sum(y => y.di.PriceTotal),
        MeasureUnit = x.Key.MeasureUnit
        Desc = x.FirstOrDefault().desc,
    })
```

```sql
SELECT
    di.Date,
    di.DisbursementNumber,
    d.DType,
    d.Note,
    d.Subscriber,
    subs.Name,
    subs.Address,
    subs.City,
    sc.ItemNumber,
    sc.StorageCardGroup,
    sc.StorageCardName,
    Sum(di.Amount) as Amount,
    di.PricePerMU,
    Sum(di.PriceTotal) as PriceTotal,
    di.MeasureUnit,
    dd.Description

FROM
    DisbursementItem as di

INNER JOIN Disbursement as d 
ON di.IDDisbursementNumber = d.DisbursementNumber

INNER JOIN Receipt as r 
ON di.IDReceiptItem = r.IDReceiptItem

INNER JOIN StorageCard as sc
ON r.ItemNumber = sc.ItemNumber

INNER JOIN DisbursementDescription dd 
ON di.IDDisbuzrsementItem = dd.IDDisbursementItem

WHERE 
    di.Date <= ... and di.Date >= ...

GROUP BY
di.DisbursementNumber, sc.ItemNumber, di.MeasureUnit
```

That is the query in SQL that I want to achieve in EF

This query can take over a minute for a few hundred rows. How can I optimize it? I suspect the multiple joins is a problem and maybe also the `Sum` of some fields.

Also the database schema cannot be modified.

The query it generate is enormous. It's like a SELECT in SELECT in SELECT for like 40 times.

Comment: Don't join explicitly like that. Use `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq

Comment: MS docs for `Include()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, don't give bad advises. `Include` with `GroupBy` has no sense.

Comment: Why is that @SvyatoslavDanyliv?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, because `Include` for loading related entities not for query generation. With `GroupBy` there is no loading related entities - OP specifies exactly which fields are needed for result.

Comment: I'm guessing the multiple `FirstOrDefault` is messing things up. What if you do `.Select(x => { var disburse = x.FirstOrDefault().di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement; return new { Date = disburs.Date, ...` so you only reference `FirstOrDefault` once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to add all fields which are needed for result to grouping key. Rewritten query to Query syntax for readability and maintainability:

```cs
DateTime from;
DateTime to;

var query = 
    from di in context.DisbursementItem
    where di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Date <= to && di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Date >= from
    join dd in context.DisbursementDescription on di.IDDisbursementItem equals dd.IDDisbursementItem
    join r in context.Receipt on di.IDReceiptItem equals r.IDReceiptItem
    join sc in context.StorageCard on r.ItemNumber equals sc.ItemNumber
    group di by new 
    {
        di.DisbursementNumber, 
        sc.ItemNumber, 
        di.MeasureUnit, 
        di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Date, 
        di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.DType, 
        di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Note,
        Subscriber = di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.Subscriber,
        SubscriberName = di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.SubscriberModel.Name,
        SubscriberAddress = di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.SubscriberModel.Address,
        SubscriberCity = di.Disbursement_IDDisbursement.SubscriberModel.City,
        sc.ItemNumber,
        sc.StorageCardGroup,
        sc.StorageCardName,
        di.PricePerMU,
        Desc = dd.Description
    } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Date,
        g.Key.DisbursementNumber,
        g.Key.DType,
        g.Key.Note,
        g.Key.Subscriber,
        g.Key.SubscriberName,
        g.Key.SubscriberAddress,
        g.Key.SubscriberCity,
        g.Key.ItemNumber,
        g.Key.StorageCardGroup,
        g.Key.StorageCardName,
        g.Key.PricePerMU,
        g.Key.MeasureUnit,
        g.Key.Desc,

        Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount),
        PriceTotal = g.Sum(x => x.PriceTotal)        
    }
```

Comment: That did indeed boost the performance. May I know why? What's the logic behind it? Is it really the `.FirstOrDefault()` what slows the query that much?

Comment: Yes, It is problem with `FirstOrDefault()`. To generate SQL for your query EF should create JOIN to grouping query and get first item from joined table. And it repeats for every `FirstOrDefault()`, everything because it is not natural for the SQL to get first element of the group. If you care about performance and know SQL, use query syntax and write LINQ query in similar way.

Answer (score 0):

you could try some kind of multithreading

the query could be splitted in parts and each part assigned to a task. in here you should find something useful (parallel section):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks?view=net-6.0