# How to use .Include() in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, one-to-many

In my Xamarin project with SQLite-net-pcl I try to use `.Include()` but get an error :

> Error CS1061 'AsyncTableQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'AsyncTableQuery' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Database:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;
using RelationDatabase.Models;
using System;
namespace RelationDatabase.Data
{
    public class NoteDatabase
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public NoteDatabase(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<Note>().Wait();
            database.CreateTableAsync<Artikel>().Wait();
        }

        //-------------------Note-------------------
        public Task<List<Note>> GetNotesAsync()
        {
            //Get all notes.
            return database.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<Note>> GetNotesInclude() 
        {
            return await database.Table<Note>().Include("artikel").ToListAsync();
        }
```

How to use `.Include()` in Xamarin or is there some other technique?

Comment: you need to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I added it but it still doesn't work @Jason

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq). `.Include("tableB")` is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.Id = tableB.tableAId;
```

And then you can use `SQLiteAsyncConnection.QueryAsync<T>(string query, params object[] args)`. Add the above sql statement to query.

Comment: You can also refer to this doc: [Xamarin.Forms Local Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases#lazy-initialization).